# How do I call a Web Service in VB6?

Tags: vb6, soap, web-services

I have an old VB 6 Application. I now want to access a Web service/web method in it, I am using MSSOAPLib30 DLL for the interaction.

Everything is fine with the simple types like `int string`.

But I am unable to send Complex types like `Class` and `Structs`.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Type Mapper.

[Microsoft SOAP Toolkit Type Mappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480501.aspx)

If you have the opportunity, you can make things much easier by creating the code to call the web service in VB.NET and then using interop to invoke it from VB 6.0.

[Calling Web Services from Visual Basic 6, the Easy Way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730836(VS.80).aspx)